# Fail in using gRPC Web Dev Tools Chrome extension in my Angular Ionic 5 project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools, grpc-web

I have an Ionic5 app built using Angular11 which is connected to a gRPC Web back-end.
I want to be able to debug and decode data coming from the server.
I installed the 'gRPC Web Developer Tools' from SafetyCulture on Chrome but the debug tool doesn't display anything.

So then I added this in the

```
home.page.ts

const enableDevTools = (window as any).__GRPCWEB_DEVTOOLS__ || (() => { });
const client = new APIServiceClient('http://172.11.56.99:7017/proxy/grpc', null, null);
enableDevTools([
    client,
]);
```

But still not working. Unfortunately there' very little documentation.
Thanks in advance.